# How to configure a server to support 10-20 hp thin clients

Tags: configuration, printer, thin-client, shared-printers

Please I need step by step instructions on how to configure and connect hp thin clients to a window 7 and 8 server.

I also need step by step instructions on how to connect POS thermal printer to the server so that it can be accessible to all the thin clients

.The thing is this. I have a machine running Windows 7. And I have 10 hp thin clients. I want to configure the machine running Windows 7 to serve as a central server to which I can connect the thin clients. it's windows embedde

Any help would be appreciated. I am having a heck of a time trying to figure it out on my own

Comment: You miss important detail, thin os or windows embeded the thin ?

Comment: The thing is this. I have a machine running Windows 7.  And I have 10 hp thin clients. I want to configure the machine running Windows 7 to serve as a central server to which I can connect the thin clients. it's windows embedded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A machine running Windows 7 or 8 is not a server, by definition. It will allow a single client to connect to a remote desktop, and it will limit overall client connections (file sharing, printer sharing) to ten clients, if I don’t misremember.

Instead you will want to look into actual Windows Server operating systems (2016, 2019), and license up to use the Remote Desktop Services feature. If you have no previous experience, it may well be cheaper to hire a consultant and hang off their back to learn what they do than to learn everything from scratch on a deadline.

The printer - as long as it’s supported by your Windows version - should be the least of your problems here, if it’s connected directly to the terminal server.